# Recommendations for Long-form Essayists

Tags: discussion

I am wondering if anyone can recommend some exemplary Japanese essayists (or Essay collections), preferably whose content is accessible in digital format (though this is not strictly necessary--physical books are definitely OK). Whether they're a columnist, creative essayist, or otherwise is fine with me--whatever you've found interesting.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not that *long*, but definitely check out Itoi Shigesato's [*Hobo Nikkan Shimbun*](http://www.1101.com/home.html) (aka ほぼ日、「今日のダーリン」).  Despite the name, it's been running daily without a miss *since 1996*, making it one of the longest-running essay blogs in the world (it predates the word "blog", thus *shimbun*).  It's digital and the latest essay is always free; collections and selections are available in book form.

Also check out the Murakamis (Haruki and Ryū), who both have well-received essay collections, many of them with ebook editions at amazon.jp; and if you want something for intermediate learners, there's also *Read Real Japanese Essays*, which can double as a way of getting to know essayists you like.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

[Find amazon.co.jp with the keyword エッセイ](https://www.amazon.co.jp/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?__mk_ja_JP=%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A&url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=%E3%82%A8%E3%83%83%E3%82%BB%E3%82%A4https://www.amazon.co.jp/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?__mk_ja_JP=%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A&url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=%E3%82%A8%E3%83%83%E3%82%BB%E3%82%A4)